# Android service mysql - check for database change

Tags: android, mysql, android-service

I'm developing android application. I need to run service to check for database update every few seconds and notify the user if changed.

Is the use of service a good way to solve this problem?

Here is part of my code. So far I didn't make it work.

Any help?

```
public class NotificationService extends Service  {

private Timer mTimer;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public String formattedDate, restoredText;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.schedule(timerTask,2000,15*1000);
    Log.d("TEST","TEST");

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try{

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.e("Log", "Running");
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        restoredText = prefs.getString("username", null);
        if (restoredText != null) {

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
            //notifiy(); //ovdje cemo ga privremeno iskljuciti

            /*

                here I need implement code for checking data from remotly mysql database
            */


        }else {
            notifiy();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: DOn't.  Performance will suck, your network traffic use will be horrible, and you'll kill battery.  Look into push messaging instead.

Comment: Use GCM notification for updates. It is best way to get updates and reduce network and battery usage.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at this tutorial. It explains a lot.

[How to sync remote mysql db to sqlite on android](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-remote-mysql-db-to-sqlite-on-android/)